# Cannot access store with connect in React-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using React in my application. I am using connect to access the store, Briefly I have this code:

```
class MyComponent extends Component{
   constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render(){
      let components = this.props.components;
      if(components.indexOf("SomeString")){
           //some stuffs
      }
        return (
            <SomeElement/>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        components: state.someReducer.components
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Components is an array of strings, if I print with `console.log(this.props.components)` inside the render function, the I am able to see the array in the browser console. However, if I try to find a value inside that array using `indexOf` then I get this error:

```
TypeError: components is undefined
```

So, What am I missing? I tried many things without result

Comment: did you define an initial state for the `someReducer` reducer?

Comment: @elas yes, indeed when I print the array in the console I see the values and they're correct

Comment: I can be sure with the error that components is getting undefined one reason or another, The problem doesn't lie in the snippet you provided.. maybe its there somewhere higher up. As the others already said, provide a check before rendering the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first cycle, `this.props.components` is undefined. You can bypass it using

```
render(){
      if(this.props.components) {
      let components = this.props.components;
      if(components!=null || components!=undefined){ //this will check if components is null or undefined
        if(components.indexOf("SomeString")){
           //some stuffs
        }}
          return (
            <SomeElement/>
          )
    }
```

Comment: ok, but now my question is: why is the array printed in the console pretty well? and it's at first cycle

Comment: Where did you put the console.log? .render() is the first part to be calles in a react lifecycle.

Comment: I out it inside render

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the `this.props.components` like so:

```
render(){
      if(this.props.components) {
        let components = this.props.components;
        if(components.indexOf("SomeString")){
           //some stuffs
        }
        return (
           <SomeElement/>
        )
      } else {
           return(<div>Loading...</div>)
      }
 }
```